# Throw Ignorable Exception

Tags: c#, exception

How do I throw an exception that can be ignored if it isn't handled?

Say I wanted to make sure a parameter was not null, something like

```
if (param == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Param is null!");
    // if the exception isn't handled in the calling code, just return
}
```

I don't want to mess up the code calling that method if it does happen to be passed a null parameter. However, I'd still like to throw an exception in case whoever is using it does handle the exception.

I thought about using "rethrows" somehow, but I don't think that'd work.

Could this be better done with something like Contracts?

Comment: That's... not how exceptions work.

Comment: Don't you think that silently returning without doing whatever the caller wanted your method to do would be "screwing up the program"?

Comment: What about throwing a [WarningException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.warningexception(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @BlasSoriano That would get the result I want, yes. Thanks! But it feels like a dirty solution to the problem... I just think handling a "WarningException" for what really should be a ArgumentException would be a bit strange.

Comment: How about logging those exceptions in database?

Comment: It sound to me that you are handling `business/use` case with help of exception, you might consider design change to handle such cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to handle what you want to do:

- don't throw an exception. Instead just return without incurring any side effects. Of course this might not be possible to do, depending on what the purpose of your method is.
- throw the exception but also make it clear in your documentation:

  - what exceptions are thrown
  - why they are thrown

  then it is up to the caller to decide whether to handle the exception or let it bubble up.

Be aware that if you throw the exception and nobody handles it then whatever is calling your code will crash. This may be considered a breaking change and may not be a welcome change in behavior.

The general rule of thumb is that you should only throw exceptions:

- when it matters  (i.e. it is important that you communicate an error state or consequence)
- when you are changing or adding value to a state or consequence

If a null parameter value really matters because you cannot function without it, then the exception also matters and the caller should not ignore it. If the null argument doesn't matter, then don't throw an exception, instead you should return an effectively null/empty/neutral response.

Comment: While your answer doesn't precisely answer the question, it does fix the underlying problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RogueCSDev Any exception can be ignored. It just has undesirable results if *everyone* ignores it.